# Specification rule of "definition of a static data member is in the scope of its class" with a templated base class

Tags: c++, scope, static, language-lawyer, definition

The C++ specification (e.g. [C++17 [class.static] §2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.static#data-2)) says:

> The definition of a static data member is in the scope of its class.

With an example (taken from [C++14 spec](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/class.static#3)):

```
int g();
struct X {
  static int g();
};
struct Y : X {
  static int i;
};
int Y::i = g();                 // equivalent to Y::g();
```

The exact wording and example in the specification have changed over the years, for some unknown reasons, [C++11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/class.static#3) and [C++14](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/class.static#3) have a quite similar example as the above, [C++17](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.static#data-2) and [C++20](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.static.data#note-1) preferred an example initializing from a static data member. The [C++20](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.static.data#note-1) wording is also much more concise. But it seems that there is no actual change in this rule.

---

It seems that this rule [doesn't work well](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/696ce781fab1742d) for inheritance of a templated class:

```
template<int VALUE>
struct base {
    static int foo() { return VALUE; }
    static constexpr int z = -1;
};

template<int VALUE>
struct foobar: base<VALUE> {
    static int x1;
    static int x2;
    static int y1;
    static int y2;
};

int foo() { return 42; }

int z = 999;

template<int VALUE>
int foobar<VALUE>::x1 = foobar::foo();

template<int VALUE>
int foobar<VALUE>::x2 = foo();

template<int VALUE>
int foobar<VALUE>::y1 = foobar::z;

template<int VALUE>
int foobar<VALUE>::y2 = z;

int main() {
    std::cout << foobar<10>::x1 << ' ' << foobar<10>::x2 << ' '
              << foobar<10>::y1 << ' ' << foobar<10>::y2;
}
```

Output:

```
10 42 -1 999
```

Both GCC 10.2 and Clang 5.0.0 agree on the above (surprising?) output.

**Is it the right output, or is it a bug in both compilers?**

The expected output, expecting that calling `foo()`, in the context of a static member initialization, would behave as calling `foobar::foo()`, etc., should be:

```
10 10 -1 -1
```

---

<sub>Note: the behavior for [inheritance](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb05244e871db1cd) as well as for [a template class without inheritance](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/907c2cd44d6621ed) and [a template base with a non-template derived](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e4383b4e977df8a), all seems to work correctly.</sub>

Comment: please add the expected output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GCC and Clang are both correct.

Particularly, from [[temp.dep]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.dep#3) [**emphasis** mine]:

> In the definition of a class or class template, **the scope of a
> dependent base class is not examined during unqualified name lookup**
> either **at the point of definition of the class** template or **member** or
> during an instantiation of the class template or member. [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> typedef double A;
> template<class T> class B {
>   typedef int A;
> };
> template<class T> struct X : B<T> {
>   A a;              // a has type double
> };
> ```
>
> The type name `A` in the definition of `X<T>` binds to the `typedef`
> name defined in the global namespace scope, not to the `typedef` name
> defined in the base `class B<T>`.  — *end example* ] [...]

In the definitions the static data members `x1` and `y1` of the of derived class template `foobar`:

```
template<int VALUE>
int foobar<VALUE>::x1 = foobar::foo();

template<int VALUE>
int foobar<VALUE>::y1 = foobar::z;
```

you are using the *injected-class-name* ([[temp.local]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.local#3)) to access the *dependent names* ([[temp.res]/9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.res#9)) `foo` and `z` from the `base` class template, whereas the unqualified names used in the definitions of the static data members `x2` and `y2` will not examine the scope of the dependent base class.

---

Note that we may bring in the names of the dependent `base` class into the scope of the derived class, redefining `foobar` as

```
template<int VALUE>
struct foobar: base<VALUE> {
    using base<VALUE>::foo;
    using base<VALUE>::z;
    static int x1;
    static int x2;
    static int y1;
    static int y2;
};
```

in which case the output of your program will be

```
10 10 -1 -1
```

Answer (score 3):

This is just another case of the binding rules for non-depended names, which are looked up and bound at the point of template definition. (Not to be confused with ADL! Even while ADL would help with the call to `foo()` if it had any parameter.)
For the full details please read here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name

Similar artifact happens with calling a function from template base class:

```
template <typename T>
struct A
{
    void f(){}
};

template <typename T>
struct B : A<T>
{
    void g()
    {
        A<T>::f();     // of course works
        this->f();     // this-> makes it depended, so it's bound only on instantiation time

        f();           // compilation error, no f() found

        using A<T>::f; // make the name available (and depended on the template)
        f();           // now it works
    }
};
```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/39KGvM